# Using PHP Group Clients Array by ID

Tags: php

Bare with me, I am new to Stack Overflow and learning PHP. I use Stack Overflow a lot to work through my code and learn. This is the first time I have a hiccup I can't resolve.

I tried a few samples located here and none are giving me the results I need.

**Here is my Array**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1001675
        [firstname] => Person One First
        [lastname] => Person One Last
        [type] => Seller
    ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 1001675
        [firstname] => Person Two First
        [lastname] => Person Two Last
        [type] => Buyer
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 1001675
        [firstname] => Person Three First
        [lastname] => Person Three Last
        [type] => Buyer
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [id] => 1006111
        [firstname] => Person Four First
        [lastname] => Person Four Last
        [type] => Seller
    )
    [4] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1006111
        [firstname] => Person Five First
        [lastname] => Person Five Last
        [type] => Buyer
    )
)
```

I stated with a foreach, and then added the following to group by id *(which I found here)*.

```
$group_clients = array();
foreach ($clients AS $client) {
    $group_clients[$client['id']][] = array(
        'firstname' => $client['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $client['lastname'],
        'type' => $client['type']
    );
}
```

This is where I am running into trouble. It produces 9 clients in my array for ID 1001675, and 4 clients for ID 1006111.

```
Array (
    [1001675] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person One First
            [lastname] => Person One Last
            [type] => Seller
        ) 
        [1] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person Two First
            [lastname] => Person Two Last
            [type] => Buyer
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person Three First
            [lastname] => Person Three Last
            [type] => Buyer
        )
        [3] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person One First
            [lastname] => Person One Last
            [type] => Seller
        ) 
        [4] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person Two First
            [lastname] => Person Two Last
            [type] => Buyer
        )
        [5] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person Three First
            [lastname] => Person Three Last
            [type] => Buyer
        )
        [6] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person One First
            [lastname] => Person One Last
            [type] => Seller
        ) 
        [7] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person Two First
            [lastname] => Person Two Last
            [type] => Buyer
        )
        [8] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person Three First
            [lastname] => Person Three Last
            [type] => Buyer
        )
    )
)
```

I tried grouping by client type as well as the id, and that only generated 1 of each value (last) in my array. I am really looking for the above, and only include the value once for each client.

**End result I am looking for:**

```
Array (
    [1001675] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person One First
            [lastname] => Person One Last
            [type] => Seller
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person Two First
            [lastname] => Person Two Last
            [type] => Buyer
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person Three First
            [lastname] => Person Three Last
            [type] => Buyer
        )
    )
    [1006111] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person Four First
            [lastname] => Person Four Last
            [type] => Seller
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [firstname] => Person Five First
            [lastname] => Person Five Last
            [type] => Buyer
        )
    )
)
```

Help would be appreciated in pointing me in the right direction to a solution on here to help me figure this out. I don't want someone to create the solution, only way to learn this is if I do it. Looking for a nudge only. Thanks

Comment: An what are your intentions? What shall be produced?

Comment: Last array shown in my post. I will change it to say End Results. Thanks Tom

Comment: So you are trying to filter to only elements with ID 1001675?

Comment: That is just one sample, looking to group everything by id. Which I have. Except, it cycles through the results more than once. That part I cannot figure out why or how to remove.

Comment: The code you presented will not produce that output for the array you have given at the beginning of the question. You can test [here](https://3v4l.org/VhjmM). It appears that `$clients` is not what you think it is.